# How to check if 3 parameters are null or undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it better to insert an if statement for null and undefined parameter checking inside the function? or should i make another function for null and undefined parameter check? i'm confused with the difference.

I have this block of code but i'm not sure whether to use if statement inside the function because i don't really know where to place it or i should just give up and make another function below it?

```
function noManagement(code, digit, input) {

        var inputArr = input.split("");

    let result = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
        inputArr.unshift(0);

            if (inputArr.length === digit) {
        result = code + inputArr.join("");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

if i insert an if statement for null and undefined checking, where should i put the return statement?

and i have another function to call the function

```
function showOutput(){
       var input=document.getElementById("search-input").value;
       var dislay=document.getElementById("search-output");
       dislay.value=noManagement("A", 9, input);
    }
```

Comment: Make your life easier and define appropriate default values for your function parameters:

     `function noManagement(code = '', digit = 0, input = []) {`

Comment: @connexo—that doesn't stop passing of the wrong type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is as follows:

```
function noManagement(code, digit, input) {
  if (arguments.length < 3) throw "Not enough arguments";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] == null) throw "Bad argument";
  }

  var inputArr = input.split("");

  let result = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
    inputArr.unshift(0);

    if (inputArr.length === digit) {
      result = code + inputArr.join("");
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Though, since your arguments are expected to be String, Number, String

```
function noManagement(code, digit, input) {
  if (typeof code !== 'string') throw "first argument should be String";
  if (typeof digit !== 'number') throw "second argument should be Number";
  if (typeof input !== 'string') throw "third argument should be String";

  var inputArr = input.split("");

  let result = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
    inputArr.unshift(0);

    if (inputArr.length === digit) {
      result = code + inputArr.join("");
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The second argument doesn't have to be a number, `'3'` will work just as well as `3`.  ;-)

Comment: I understand that, the first argument also doesn't have to be a string, just something that will be coerced to a string when used with `+` - but I don't think that's the intent of the function :p

Comment: if i input 123 it should output, A000000123. But if i input "+" or any other special character or i input nothing it should ouput the error message right? but it just outputs A00000000+ or A00000000" "

Comment: I don't know what your code is supposed to do - I answered the question you asked, nothing else

Comment: @newgrammer - why? that duplicate answers the question you asked - if you have a different question (which you seem to do based on the comment) then that's hardly anyone's fault your question got closed

Comment: @Bravo thanks for helping man! i appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple addition that will check for undefined. it will stop the function from executing if any of the three are not provided

```
function noManagement(code, digit, input) {
    if (!code) throw new Error("code is undefined");
    if (!digit) throw new Error("digit is undefined");
    if (!input) throw new Error("input is undefined");

    var inputArr = input.split("");

    let result = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
        inputArr.unshift(0);

            if (inputArr.length === digit) {
        result = code + inputArr.join("");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this will also "detect" if any of these are `''` or `0` or `false` ... not what the question asked for

Comment: `if (!code)` may result in many false positives as Bravo says. Add `NaN` to the list. Consider `let checkVal = val => !(val === null || typeof val === 'undefined');` returns true if *val* is not null or undefined.